# There's a way to download large files direct from server? (Without waiting for blob response)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So, I'm working on the request of video files (using axios). I made the requests w/ the `responseType: blob` and wait for the response to create the video player with the `window.URL.createObjectUrl()`. But I've a button too, when the user click he can download the file.

**The problem is:** most files has big sizes, 150MB+, which turns out to be terrible for the user to wait for the blob response and start downloading.

There's a better way to do that? Without waiting for the response and making the browser handle the request?

Comment: Why can't you just link to it like anything else?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do better through an XHR request (beside displaying a loading element while waiting for request response).

But why can't you just pass it through the browser (using the `<a>` element on-the-fly creation trick)? If you paste your end-point on browser's location bar, doesn't it open or download it?

Comment: Nope, the download doesn't start when I paste on the browser. And w/ the ``<a>``  element I've the same problem: need to wait for the blob response to link on the tag.

Comment: Well, then it's a backend issue. You've to send the file the right way. All I can say is our Java backend is sending a response (with content-type and content-disposition indeed) with the file content in the body using an org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamResource